# MariaDB native UTC time on update

Tags: sql, mariadb, utc, onupdate

I’m searching for a value that changes the value of a column to the current UTC time when the row is updated, but UTC_TIMESTAMP and GETUTCDATE only works as default value, not when used in ON UPDATE.

Is there a solution or do I have to give the database the UTC time manually via the application.

P.S. CURRENT_TIMESTAMP works, but does not give UTC time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a default value to automatically increment on an update:

This column updates only on insert:

```
inserted_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

This column updates on insert or update:

```
updated_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=ea2eaf2813c26df9415b72cdd61142d6) is a db<>fiddle.

Note:  These work with `timestamp` as well as `datetime`, if that is your preference.

Comment: current_timestamp works indeed, but that does not give the UTC time which is why I’m still searching.

Comment: @NoahSnoeks . . . The value is stored internally as UTC.  You can use `convert_tz()` to convert *back* to UTC when you need to.  The "visible" timestamp is just a convenience.